# Grepping second pattern after matching first pattern

Tags: regex, perl, sed, grep, tcl

Is there any grep/sed option which will allow me to match a pattern after matching another pattern? For example: Input file (`foo`s are variable patterns starting with `0` mixed with random numbers preceded by `#` in front):

```
0foo1  
0foo2  
0foo3  
\#89888  
0foo4  
0foo5  
\#98980  
 0foo6
```

So once I try to search for a variable pattern (eg. `foo2`), I also want to match another pattern (eg, `#number`) from this pattern line number, in this case, `#89888`.

Therefore output for variable `foo2` must be:

```
foo2  #89888
```

For variable `foo5`:

```
foo5  #98980
```

`foo`s consist of every character, including which may be considered metacharacters.

I tried a basic regex match script using tcl which will first search for `foo*` and then search for next immediate `#`, but since I am working with a very large file, it will take days to finish. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you use [pcregrep](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pcregrep/info) instead, which has multiline support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Perl one-liner to slurp the whole file and match across any newlines for the pattern you seek would look like:

```
perl -000  -nle 'm{(foo2).*(\#89888)}s and print join " ",$1,$2' file
```

The `-000` switch enables "slurp" mode which signals Perl not to split the file into chunks, but rather treat it as one large string.  The `s` modifier lets `.` match any character, including a newline.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
$ awk -v tgt="foo2" 'index($0,tgt){f=1} f&&/#[0-9]/{print tgt, $0; exit}' file
foo2 \#89888

$ awk -v tgt="foo5" 'index($0,tgt){f=1} f&&/#[0-9]/{print tgt, $0; exit}' file
foo5 \#98980
```

I'm using `index()` above as it searches for a string not a regexp and so could not care less what RE metacharacters are in foo - they are all just literal characters in a string.

It's not clear from your question if you want to find a specific number after a specific foo or the first number after foo2 or even if you want to search for a specific foo value or all "foo"s or...

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my ( %matches, $recent_foo );

while(<DATA>)
{
   chomp;
   ( $matches{$recent_foo} ) = $1 if m/(\\#\d+)/;
   ( $recent_foo ) = $1 if m/(0foo\d+)/;
}

print Dumper( \%matches );

__DATA__
0foo1  
0foo2  
0foo3  
\#89888  
0foo4  
0foo5  
\#98980  
 0foo6

 ./perl 
$VAR1 = {
          '0foo5' => '\\#98980',
          '0foo3' => '\\#89888'
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is `0foo1`, `0foo2` and `0foo3` to all have the same value the following will do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my ( %matches, @recent_foo );

while(<DATA>)
{
   chomp;
   if (/^\\#/)
   {
     @matches{@recent_foo} = ($') x @recent_foo;
     undef @recent_foo;
   }
   elsif (/^0/)
   {
     push @recent_foo, $';
   }
}

print Dumper( \%matches );

__DATA__
0foo1
0foo2
0foo3
\#89888
0foo4
0foo5
\#98980
0foo6
```

gives:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'foo2' => '89888',
          'foo1' => '89888',
          'foo5' => '98980',
          'foo3' => '89888',
          'foo4' => '98980'
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Var='foo2'
sed "#n
/${Var}/,/#[0-9]\{1,\}/ {
   H
   /#[0-9]\{1,\}/ !d
   s/.*//;x
   s/.//;s/\n.*\\n/ /p
   q
   }" YourFile
```

Not clear as request. It take first occurence of your pattern *foo2* until first *#number*, remove line between and print both line in 1 than quit (no other extract

Answer (score 0):

A Tcl solution. The procedure runs in a little over 3 microseconds, so you'll need *very* large data files to have it run for days. If more than one token matches, the first match is used (it's easy to rewrite the procedure to return all matches).

```
set data {
0foo1  
0foo2  
0foo3  
\#89888  
0foo4  
0foo5  
\#98980  
 0foo6
}

proc find {data pattern} {
    set idx [lsearch -regexp $data $pattern]
    if {$idx >= 0} {
        lrange $data $idx $idx+1
    }
}

find $data 0foo3
# -> 0foo3 #89888
find $data 0f.*5
# -> 0foo5 #98980
```

Documentation: [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lrange](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrange.htm), [lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Answer (score 0):

sed

```
sed -n '/foo2/,/#[0-9]\+/ {s/^[[:space:]]*[0\\]//; p}' file | 
sed -n '1p; $p' | 
paste -s
```

- The first sed prints all the lines between the first pattern and the 2nd, removing optional leading whitespace and the leading `0` or `\`.
- The second sed extracts only the first and last lines.
- The paste command prints the 2 lines as a single line, separated with a tab.

---

awk

```
awk -v p1=foo5 '
    $0 ~ p1 {found = 1} 
    found && /#[0-9]+/ { sub(/^\\\/, ""); print p1, $0; exit }
' file
```

---

tcl

```
lassign $argv filename pattern1
set found false
set fid [open $filename r]
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    if {[string match "*$pattern1*" $line]} {
        set found true
    }
    if {$found && [regexp {#\d+} $line number]} {
        puts "$pattern1 $number"
        break
    }
}
close $fid
```

Then

```
$ tclsh 2patt.tcl file foo4
foo4 #98980
```